# constant length of blocks in partitions

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

Let's assume we have partitions $P_k$ of the set $\{1,...,n\}$. If we choose two partitions it can happen, that each of them has a constant length of its blocks, but that the intersection of these two partitions does not have this property. For example: $\{\{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6\}\}$ and $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}\}$.

Let's now consider the case that each P_k and each pairwise intersection have constant length of blocks. My question is: Does then every arbitrary intersection has this property, too?

I think they do not have to, but i have not managed to find a counterexample.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What is the intersection of the partitions $\{\{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6\}\}$ and $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}\}$ in your case? Strictly speaking, it is an empty set, since the two sets have no elements in common.

Comment: I mean the "intersection" in the lattice of the partitions. In this case: {{1,2},{3},{4},{5,6}}
It is just the coarsest refinement of the others.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming by intersection of the two partitions you mean for each element $x$ in the set we make it the element of a new block of the new partition: the partitions of elements that belong to Block $a$ in the first partition, and block $\alpha$ in the second. Is this correct?

Consider the following partition of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$

$P_1=\{\{1,2,3,4\},\{5,6,7,8\}\},P_2=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\},\{7,8\}\}$.

Their intersection is $P_2$ which once again has blocks of constant length, so it is possible.

A sufficient condition is for the length of the blocks of one of the partitions to be a multiple of the lengths of the blocks of the other partition.

An example that "refines the partition"  on the set $\{1,2,3\dots 360\}$.

$P_1$: congrunce classes $\bmod 9$

$P_2$: congruence classes $\bmod 4$

$P_3$: congruences classes $\bmod 5$

$P_1\cap P_2\cap P_3:$ congruence classes $\bmod 180$ (each of the blocks has size $2$)

---

As for the counterexample take set $\{1,2,3\dots 36\}$

$P_1$ is congruence $\bmod 2$.

$P_2$ is congruence $\bmod 3$

$P_3$ is $\{1,2,3,19,20,24\},\{7,8,9,25,26,30\},\{13,14,15,31,32,36\},\{4,5,6,21,22,23\},\{10,11,12,27,28,29\},\{16,17,18,33,34,35\}$

Comment: Do you mean {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8}} instead of {1,2},{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8}} ?

Comment: Maybe my question is unclear. Let's say that $P_1, P_2, P_3$ are partitions having constant length of blocks and $P_1 \cap P_2, P_2 \cap P_3$ and $P_1 \cap P_3$ have constant length of blocks, too. Does then $P_1 \cap P_2 \cap P_3$ has constant length of blocks?

Comment: I have updated my result, I now give an example with $3$ partitions.

Comment: And can we say that it's a general valid statement?

Comment: It is possible to build a set of $k$ partitions for any $k$, just select the set $\{1,2\dots p_1p_2\dots p_k\}$ where $p_i$ is the $i$'th prime. And as partitions select the congruence classes modulo each of the primes up to $p_k$

Comment: Ok, now I am looking for a counterexample: Is there any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and are there any three partitions $P_1, P_2,P_3$ of {1,...,n} having constant block length, so that $P_1\cap P_2, P_2\cap P_3,P_1 \cap P_3$ have constant block length, but $P_1\cap P_2 \cap P_3$ does not have this property.

Comment: I have uploaded a counterexample

Comment: Sorry, i can't see that $P_3$ is a partition...

Comment: Ok, I have fixed it.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer